# Why isn't `link_to` going to the route I've specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes, view

I have these routes from running `rake routes`:

```
     workstations POST   /workstations(.:format)      workstations#create
 new_workstations GET    /workstations/new(.:format)  workstations#new
edit_workstations GET    /workstations/edit(.:format) workstations#edit
                  GET    /workstations(.:format)      workstations#show
                  PUT    /workstations(.:format)      workstations#update
                  DELETE /workstations(.:format)      workstations#destroy
                  POST   /                            workstations#delete_history_and_queue
```

I have this `link_to` in my view:

`= link_to "Update", controller: "workstations", method: "put"`

Yet I'm getting this error:

`No route matches {:controller=>"workstations", :method=>"put"}`

Have I not specified for the link to use the `workstations` controller with the `put` method, which should, in theory, lead to the `workstations#update` action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
= link_to "Update", edit_workstations_path, :method => :put
```

OR

```
= link_to "Update", '/workstations', :method => :put
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the following:

```
= link_to "Update", workstations_path, :method => :put
```

And it looks like you generated a singular resource in your routes.rb... was that intentional?